# Why can't signtool find certificate in machine store?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssl, certificate, mmc

We have a code signing certificate that is working in TeamCity builds using the following command:

```
signtool sign /a /v /sm /s my /n "NAME_ISSUED_TO" /d "DESCRIPTION" FILENAME
```

Unfortunately the person who set this up is no longer here and we need to reconfigure things. We are currently trying to run the command from a console on the machine and we get the following error:

**SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.**

The certificate is stored in the "Local Computer" area of the certificate store which is what I understand the /sm command relates to.

Any ideas why it wouldn't work from the console?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Have you verified the certificate is stored for the user running the command?  Its installed on the machine, but the command, is likely look at the certificate used by the user.

Comment: Yes, I have verified this. There are two certificates in the store, I can sign with one but not with the other (it gives the error above).